# I'm having an issue with my flutter registration with mysql and php

Tags: android, ios, sql, flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter. The registration is not working with mysql and php. here is my code.

```
      Future register() async {
var url = "http://192.168.0.142/register.php";
var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
    // header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'),
    body: {
  "username": user.text,
  "password": pass.text,
});

if(response.body.isNotEmpty) {
  debugPrint("not empty ${user.text}");

  json.decode(response.body);
}
else
{
  debugPrint("empty ${user.text}");

}
var data = json.decode(response.body);
if (data == "Error") {
  // FlutterToast(context).showToast(
  //     child: Text(
  //       'User allready exit!',
  //       style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.red),
  //     ));


  print("already");

} else {
  // FlutterToast(context).showToast(
  //     child: Text('Registration Successful',
  //         style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.green)));
  // Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>DashBoard(),),);
  print("seccussfull");
}
```

}

here is my registration.php file

```
     <?php
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','userdata');
    if (!$db) {
        echo "Database connection faild";
    }
    else
    {
    
    echo "Success";

     }

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT username FROM login WHERE username = '".$username."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($count == 1) {
        echo json_encode("Error");
    }else{
        $insert = "INSERT INTO          login(username,password)VALUES('".$username."','".$password."')";
        $query = mysqli_query($db,$insert);
        if ($query) {
            echo json_encode("Success");
        }
    }

?>
```

I'm getting this error

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
Success
^

#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1405:5)
#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1272:9)
#2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:937:22)
#3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:40:10)
#4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:612:36)
#5      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:216:41)
#6      _RegisterState.register (package:employeessql/register.dart:31:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

The login is working by adding manual data. But the registration is not working.

I have tried every way. Please help. It is related with json.decode. Also I want to know how I can update the data according to current user. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Remove `echo "Success";`, its not part of the json response but your flutter code will try to parse it anyway

Comment: P.s. this php code is horrendously insecure. Please learn about preventing sql injection, and about how to hash passwords.

Comment: Is this academic code for learning, or production code you intend to deploy?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: Thank you @ADyson. Will do that. Can you give me the solution of error please

Comment: It is just for learning @tadman

Comment: That's great, but it's absolutely important to learn how to use placeholder values, and to learn to use them *as a matter of course*. The way you're just slapping together a query here is going to lead to all kinds of trouble down the road that can be easily avoided by doing it properly.

Comment: Noted :) @tadman. But what is the problem with the error

Comment: You've apparently got an error in your Dart code, which has nothing to do with either of the tags you've applied, so maybe correct that to focus on the problem at hand.

Comment: Thanks @tadman. I have tried to check every possible way but it is not working. Also I'm new to flutter

Comment: It'd really help us if you better explained *how* you got that error, and what changes you made in your code that lead to that problem occurring, if you know. I'm not entirely familiar with Dart, but that looks like a JSON parsing failure caused by invalid JSON being produced somewhere.

Comment: I have tried to decode JSON with has map
    var data = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
doesn't work. the problem is with decoding json @tadman

Answer (score 1):

If you're emitting JSON as your final result:

- Set the appropriate content-type
- Render **only** JSON, and *absolutely* nothing else

For the header:

```php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Note in your example you `echo "Success"` before your JSON, which means you're actually dumping garbage into the result stream. `Success"Success"` is not a valid JSON document.

Comment: Will remove the success. but adding the header gives me this error
Too many positional arguments: 1 expected, but 2 found. (Documentation)

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific about what line of code produced that error. You're making us work really hard to figure out what you're even talking about.

Comment: it is this line.     var data = json.decode(response.body);

Comment: `console.log(response.body)` to see what you're working with. Do some debugging here, it'll help.

Comment: it is showing null. I'm just inserting data to mysql to register @tadman

Comment: Maybe you're missing a body handler.

Comment: what is that exactly @tadman

Comment: It's how Node (Express) apps parse the body, and it is optional, you must install it and configure it as part of your stack. Not sure if Flutter has the same requirement.

Comment: Alright will see

Comment: Adding the correct Content-Type header may have creates another problem, that being your server doesn't know how to handle it now. Before you were, incorrectly, parsing incoming regular body data as JSON. If you get the JSON body parser installed correctly, you shouldn't even have to decode it, `body` will be the decoded data already.

Comment: so shouldn't use header?

Comment: You absolutely *should* use a header. What you're doing now is misrepresenting your content, and assuming a lot of things that are not necessarily true. It's much better to communicate the content honestly, and to set up the correct parser for it. In Express I use the regular [`body_parser`](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html) for Node but you may need a different one, depends on your stack. I think you need something equivalent.

Comment: alright will look into that